# git client for iPhones

Tags: iphone, git

I have a private git repo on a VPS.  I put some word docs, and some excel sheets and some other non source-code files on it that I'd like to be able to access on my iPhone.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider installing a simple web server (like `lighttpd`) and hook up the built-in [Gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) interface. It allows you to browse history and view/download files.

Comment: that's a pretty good idea.  i got apache running on the server though.  can is there an apache git hook?

Comment: @SamHammamy: Gitweb works with any web server.

Comment: Yep.  I configured it for apache.  But now I need to add authentication, because I have sensitive files in the repos

Comment: @SamHammamy: There are many ways to do that; a simple `.htaccess` file would probably do it for Apache (depending on your authentication needs, of course).